# Is possible to load a document in-memory?

Tags: javascript

I need to get a pdf file from http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf using javascript so I can make a POST of this document to a REST API. 
The pdf should stay only in-memory because I only need that document to make a post request.

Is this possible to do this using browser javascript? I'm using angularjs.

```js
 $http.post("/someUrl", json) {
         ....
      }
```

Comment: I believe you will be blocked by cross-domain security. You can't call different domains from a browser, unless they explicitely allow CORS. This would be doable from a server, but a browser... I doubt it.

Comment: Can't I just get the pdf document from the url? it should be like downloading without actually downloading, it should just remain in memory so I can make the POST request

Comment: The browser would go to the URL and download it and then POST to your API. Think about changing pdf995.com for facebook.com, get the contents and forward it to your backend server. That's why browsers will not allow you to do it except if you have CORS enabled.

Comment: So the only way for me to load the pdf from the URL is using Java for example and then pass it to my frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the data into local variable and pass it to other ajax call.

```
window.binaryData = null;
$.ajax( {
  url:'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery_tutorial.pdf',
  method:'GET',
  success:function(data) {
  window.binaryData = data;
    console.log('Success => ',data);
  },
  error:function(error){
    console.log('Error => ',error);
  }
});
```

Response from ajax call can be set to variable on the window scope `window.binaryData`.

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/L6ge8f0w/

Comment: that's perfect but the reason why you cannot download the URL that I provided is because of CORS right? I get an error about CORS with that URL. is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: @user10498758 Yes browser has restricted the page to access resources on the other domain unless the server specifically provide CORS permission.

Comment: there should be another solution.

Comment: I am not aware of it.